# Как в админке django создать новую страницу с настройками?

Tags: django, django-admin

подскажите пожалуйста, как вы обычно делаете отдельную страницу, на которой можно указать все настройки сайта?

Я бы хотел, чтобы в меню админки был раздел "Настройки", при переходе на который отображается не какой то список, а конкретная страница с формой, на которой сразу можно вписать все настройки и сохранить.

Поясняю: это нужно чтобы вложить лого, название сайта, номера телефонов и прочая общая для всего сайта информация

Comment: Не уверен что это возможно и логично. Так как о каких настройках в админке (если вы о тех настройках что в settings.py) может идти речь если вам до запуска админки нужно базу прописать и т.д. Если вас интересует что то конкретное то дайте более развёрнутое описание задачи, желательно с вашей попыткой это решить)

Comment: Ну например на сайте есть лого, есть название сайта, номера телефонов и email, для таких вещей должна быть отдельная страница с настройками в админке. Можно ли такое организовать?

Comment: Просто делаю обычную модель и храню всё в ней

Comment: Ну это не очень красиво, когда у тебя модель в админке список отображает, в котором всего один элемент. Поэтому хотелось бы сделать красиво